# XML node containing an XPath expression from another XML file - how to get its value?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, zorba

File common.xml:

```
<common>
  <os1>Windows 7</os1>
</common>
```

File item.xml:

```
<item>
  <os>common/os1</os>
</item>
```

So the **os** node in the item.xml file contains an XPath expression pointing to a node in the common.xml file. How can I get the actual value of the node pointed by the XPath expression (**Windows 7**). If I use **$input-context/item/os** I get **common/os1**.

I'm using zorba-xquery and I have declared:

```
declare variable $input-context external;
declare variable $common-context external;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the eval function of the reflection module:

```
import module namespace reflection = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/reflection";

declare variable $common-context :=
  document {
    <common>
      <os1>Windows 7</os1>
    </common>
  };

declare variable $input-context :=
  document {
    <item>
      <os>common/os1</os>
    </item>
  };

let $path := $input-context/item/os/text()
let $query := fn:concat('$common-context/', $path, '/text()')
return
  reflection:eval($query)
```